# Passing Html to Jinja from Models/DB and jinja in jinja?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, jinja2

So i am coding a personal website for myself and i don't wanna add each page from views and urls. I am trying to make a very dynamic website which admins can add pages from /admin

but the problem right now is when i try to put jinja or html from my database by jinja templating. Jinja sees them as just str and directly output them raw.

I am trying to put html and jinja in jinja bcs i want to make a page editor in admin page and add pages with lots of pics and things from there with out coding. Maybe there is another way to do it then just tell me how to do it.

My English is bad but codes gonna explain everything (i gonna translate Turkish things with # python comment thing for making it more understandable:

views:

```
  from django.shortcuts import render
    from umut.models import *

    # Create your views here.

    def sayfa#page(request, sayfalinki#pagelink stands for pagename):
    içerik#content = Sayfalar.objects.get(baslik=sayfalinki)
    return render(request, "umut/umut-şablon.html" , {"içerik":içerik})
```

model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Sayfalar(models.Model):
 baslik#title = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 icerik#content = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
```

urls:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.anasayfa, name= 'anasayfa#mainpage'),
    path('<str:sayfalinki>', views.sayfa)
]
```

template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        {% load static %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "umut/umut-style.css" %}">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>{{içerik.title}}</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 class="anabaslik">Umut Özsoy</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            {% for i in sayfalar %}
                <a href="{{i.link}}">{{i.isim}}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </nav>
        <section>
        {{içerik.icerik}}
        </section>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Passing html to jinja template variable -->

`{{variable|safe}} #jinja's safe filter`

or

### making a safe area/block -->

`{%autoescape off%} blabla {%endautoescape%}`

detailed info : [Django Doc Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping)

jinja variable in jinja variable is still not working.